# Jackson JsonParser readValueAs Multimap

Tags: java, json, jackson, guava

I am trying to implement a custom deserializer using `StdDeserializer<T>`. In my `deserialize(JsonParser, DeserializationContext)` method, I'm trying to use `JsonParser` to read a [`Multimap`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap) given that the JSON string is `{ "toMap": { "a": "b", "a": "c" } }`.

Assuming I'm at a point where the field name is `"toMap"`, I've tried to do this: `Multimap<String, Object> rawConditions = jsonParser.readValuesAs(new TypeReference<LinkedListMultimap<String, Object>>() {});` but it leads to a compilation error. It says they have incompatible types - a `Multimap<String, Object>` is required, but it is finding an `Iterator<Object>`.

Comment: Could you be more specific and write what should be in your `Multimap` after parsing your example input?

Comment: I've added an answer. But if you have any control on the serialization side, it would be better to have  {"a": ["b", "c"]}  rather than  { "a": "b", "a": "c" }

Answer (score 0):

Guava's `Multimap<K, V>` is roughly equivalent to `Map<K, Collection<V>>` but in your data (`{ "toMap": { "a": "b", "a": "c" } }`) you have `Map<K, Map<V, X>>` which, of course, cannot be deserialized to `Multimap`. If you insist on using Guava, you can deserialize it to [`Table`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Table.html). Of course I assume you use [`jackson-datatypes-collections`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatypes-collections) and have `GuavaModule` registered in `ObjectMapper`.

**EDIT**: If you want to deserialize "toMap" **value** as multimap (i.e. `{ "a": "b", "a": "c" }`), it also isn't valid `Multimap<K, V>` (or `Map<K, Collection<V>>` if you want) but rather `Map<K, V>`:

- it has duplicate key `"a"`,
- it should be something like `{ "a": ["b"], "x": ["c"] }` to be a valid `Multimap`.

Try to deserialize it as `Map<String, String>` instead.

Comment: Except that the "a" key is duplicated, so it can be interpreted as a multimap.

Comment: @Joel If OP wants `"toMap"` **value** to be parsed, it's also not a valid `Multimap<K, V>` (or `Map<K, Collection<V>>` if you want) but rather `Map<K, V>`.

Comment: Don't think so. { "a": "b", "a": "c" } could be interpreted as {"a": ["b", "c"]} which, you'd agree, is ok as a multimap. Data is just data. You can interpret it the way you want.

Comment: I don't think there's deserializer for such format for Jackson in jackson-datatypes-collections - looks like some specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any built-in converter for multimaps, but assuming the multimap you're looking for in your example is `{ "a": "b", "a": "c" }` (without "toMap"), and that you expect it translates to something like `{"a": ["b", "c"]}`, you could write your own deserializer by parsing json token by token, and adding it the your multimap. Example :

```
public class CustomDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Multimap<String, String>> {

    @Override
    public Multimap<String, String> deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext dc)
            throws IOException {
        Multimap<String, String> multimap = LinkedListMultimap.create();
        JsonToken currentToken = null;
        while ((currentToken = jp.nextValue()) != null) {
            switch (currentToken) {
                case VALUE_STRING:
                    multimap.put(jp.getCurrentName(), jp.getText());
                    break;
            }
        }
        return multimap;
    }
}
```